# Running an R script in Linux

Tags: r, linux

Sorry if this is covered elsewhere. I did look but it seems my problem is far simpler than any relevant posts and my knowledge is pretty rudimentary. Anyway, here goes..

I ran the following R script on a very small test table

```
table<-read.table(file="HumanCoreExome_PhLiPS_ipsc_impute2_recoded.vcf.012.
table_t<-t(table)
write.table(table_t, file="transposed_table.txt")
```

From within Linux using

```
bsub -M 32000 Rscript test_script.r
```

And it worked fine, writing a new (transposed) table as hoped. I then tried it on my actual table, adding a couple of extra lines to give me some info, with:

```
table<-read.table(file = "large_table.txt", row.names = 1, header = TRUE)
dim(table)
class(table)
table_t<-t(table)
dim(table_t)
class(table_t)
write.table(table_t,file = "test_1_t.txt")
```

From Linux with

```
bsub -M 32000 Rscript real_script.r
```

But nothing has happened. Can anyone tell me why and how to remedy? I realize this is very basic but I'm a bit of a noob. Knowing if this is resource-related (my job seems to be running, although I don't think it should be taking this long) or just my bad code would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: How large is the `"large_table.txt"` matrix? Are you able to subset it first to test on smaller versions?

Comment: It's several million columns long (and 80 rows deep). But sure, I guess I could subset it. A question though. I know the head -INTEGER command will let me subset  a manageable number of rows but is there an equivalent for columns?

Comment: I don't think `read.table` makes that easy. If it's easily-delimited (e.g., `,`), you could go to a shell prompt and use `cut -d, -f1-20 infile > testfile` to get the first 20 columns. Alternatively, you could use `readr::read_table` and specify you want to ignore some columns, but that's a bit more work.